# Add array element from form submission

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, inserthtml

I'm learning JS and how to add array elements. I want to have the info submitted in the form as a new array element and have it displayed it below. Can't find the way to do it using JS. Can someone help? Find below my code so far, which doesn't work:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <form>
          New array element:<br>
          <input id="age" type="text" name="firstname" value="">
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
        </form> 
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
          var fruits = ["Banana", "Mango", "Apple"]
          var newArray = document.getElementById("age").value;
          fruits.push(newArray);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your `myFunction()` body?

Comment: gotcha! you are absolutely right, thanks. Someone posted the suggested code which answers my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `myFunction()` on a button click but there is no function declaration for `myFunction()` in `<scripts>`

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


New array element:<br>
<input id="age" type="text" name="firstname" value="">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Mango", "Apple"];
function myFunction(){
var newArray = document.getElementById("age").value;
fruits.push(newArray);
document.getElementById("age").value = "";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Made `fruits` array as global, i.e., moved  `var fruits = ["Banana", "Mango", "Apple"];` outside of the function as per OP's requirements.

Comment: thanks! however, when submitting more than once, array changes the last element of array instead of adding anything i submit. how would u fix this? thanks again

Comment: @perettxintxola hey, edited my answer, now the first time when the page is loaded, there will be three items in `fruits` and then every time a text is submitted, it'll update the `fruits` array.

Comment: @perettxintxola you're welcome. you could accept the answer if it met all your requirements :) thanks! cheers!

Comment: done! I've run the suggested code in my page and I've realized that the screen goes blank after pressing submit. As per the other user answer, this happens because the form is submitting. However, I don't see how I could have <p> printed in the screen, so I can see the Array printed. We're submitting the form, I don't understand why <p> disappears. Do you know how this could be fixed? Thanks again!

Comment: @perettxintxola Part1:- yeah!. First thing the purpose of `<form>` in general is to do something with the data residing under it,e.g., the input value in this case. A form has an attribute called `method` which determines what kind of action is to be taken with respect to the form data, e.g., `GET`, which "gets" some data from the server using the data present in form. Similarly there is other method, `POST`, which as it suggests, 'posts' some data to the server. One more attribute of form is called `action`. This attribute suggests where you want to navigate after you submit the page. End Par

Comment: Part2:- In this case, the `method` attribute defaults to `GET` as no `method` is mentioned on form element and the page navigates to a blank page because the `action` attribute is not there. So in this case you **do not** need `<form>` remove `<form>`, change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. I shall edit my code in the example too. Read about forms http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp . You just need a simple button which calls the js function `myFunction()` on click of it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I've edited my answer to make the i/p value blank after you click the button through this, `document.getElementById("age").value = "";`.

Comment: a-mazing. thank you so much for taking the time to explain me all this. This is really helpful and I've learned a ton with your 3 comments. THANK U! have a great day!

Comment: @perettxintxola Welcome, glad it helped so much! You too have a good day! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the behavior of `myFunction()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <form onsubmit="myFunction()">New array element:
            <br>
            <input id="age" type="text" name="firstname" value="">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var newArray = document.getElementById("age").value;
                fruits.push(newArray);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
            }
            var fruits = ["Banana", "Mango", "Apple"];
            myFunction(); // initialize demo innerHTML
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you! Make sense, array fruits needs to be outside myFunction. However, I don't understand why we add myFunction (sorry, don't understand your comment). I've noticed that if I comment myFunction(); out the screen goes blank right after clicking submit button. I'm curious to know why. Can you explain? Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I added the function call `myFunction()` so that when the page loads for the first time, it will populate `<p id="demo"></p>` with the `fruits`. Otherwise it would be blank because `myFunction()` hasn't been executed until we click submit.

Comment: The page is going blank because the form is actually submitting. Consider using `onsubmit` rather than `onclick`. I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks @preston! I understand now why screen goes blank :) However, since we are submitting the form, shouldn't <p> remain in the screen? How do you think this could be fixed so after submitting we can see the array? (Sorry of these are basic question, but i'm getting started, any help is more than welcome! :) ). Thanks again,